# Самоучитель по php

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший самоучитель по **php** для новичков (чтобы, как говорится, всё было понятно).

Comment: документация...банально да...зато действенно...

Comment: PHP 5 в подлиннике, по нему учился.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мой рецепт: сначала какой-нибудь простенький сборник уроков, чтобы показалось, что все легко и просто. Следующий момент придумываем себе задачу, не фреймворк слепить, ну и не мега портал, а к примеру делаем какой-нибудь легкий сервис(я лично делал адресную книгу для Active Directory) и набор ограниченного функционала к нему, за который ни в коем случае не вылезать. Поэтапно учимся сталкиваться с проблемами и решать их на ходу, при этом ходя в google, хэшкод, php.net и т. д. Попеременно ищем подобные реализации подобных сервисов, сравниваем и замечаем умные реализации, но без тотального копипаста.

Реализовав сей сервис, недолго восторгаемся собой и думаем что ждет пользователь в версии сервиса 0.2. До этого момента был самый страшный быдлокод))). И тут начинается развитие, любые попытки расширять сервис становятся похожими на сизифов труд. Что бы добавить какой-то функционал, надо править код в 5-10 местах, забыл в одном месте, по полчаса ищещь, не находишь, злишься и приходишь к пониманию что виноват ты, так как не придумал нормальную архитектуру. Здесь начинаешь пересматривать методы своего мышления. На этом этапе ключевыми словами, наверное будут повторяемость кода, ООП или процедурный стиль.

Далее идут попытки переделать свой сервис и сделать его лучше, если их нет то все очень плохо. Только переделывая старое, ты постоянно повышаешь себе планку качества и растешь. Берясь за новые, ты скорее повторно наступишь на те же грабли. На этом этапе будешь смотреть и интересоваться методами отладки, поиском узких мест, рефакторингом и конечно паттернами программирования. И только в этот момент стоит открывать книги и поражаться, как много ты знаешь и при этом выцеплять только незнакомые места в языке и сложные ньюансы. В этом момент книга принесет намного больше пользы, чем если читать ее будучи новичком плюс ты сам сможешь оценить ее качество.

Резюмируя: если идти в сторону качества, нужно доделывать старые проекты до удовлетворяющего вас уровня.

Comment: Жизненно...

Answer (score 4):

Все вышесказанное конечно хорошо, но товарищи. Как вы могли забыть про [мануал](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/index.php) ???

Коли ты вообще не кодил - забудь про книги. Начинай с мануала. и периодически к нему возвращайся. Уверяю тебя - php будешь знать не хуже главного знахаря=) Книги читать нужно чтоб суметь создать что-то полезное. Для начала нужно получить инструмент, а самый быстрый и эффективный способ - мануал)

Comment: а точнее документация - полностью поддерживаю!

Answer (score 3):

Не так важна книга, важна практика, начать можно с любой книги, если у вас нет опыта в программировании - не стои выбирать книгу типа "php за неделю" и т.п.
Т.к. вы новичек - советую сразу-же прочесть http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke (благо текста немного).

Если у вас нет знаний html'я - начните с него, если же есть - можете начинать :)

Я в свое время учился на книгах: "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript", "PHP Сборник рецептов" и моя любимая была - "Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования"

Вообще нужно сразу учится работать с документацией и быстро находить решения интересующих вас вопросов, ИМХО - это чуть-ли не главная черта действительно хорошего программиста(ну и естественно сразу же "слету" учится применять на практике и, желательно, запоминать)

Загадывая наперед. Основы работы с БД старайтесь учить уже тогда, когда будете иметь крепкие базовые знания дабы вы все сразу правильно понимали. В книге Никсона мне очень нравится как преподнесена работа с БД, все очень доходчиво и просто, при этом "сложности" затрагиваются, как-бы вскользь, таким образом вы запоминаете где вы можете найти эту информацию но не придаете ей большего значения. 
Скорее всего вам, так-же, предстоит выучить javascript и css.

В любом случае удачи.

На всякий случай - если нет опыта в программировании видеокурсы и видеоуроки категорически противопоказаны.

Comment: Это не копипаст, это так теги обработались...

Comment: Спасибо! Опыт з html уже есть, буду начинать учить php

Answer (score 2):

Все эти самоучитель до одного места. Было бы желание.

Я работал тестировщиком на одной конторе, работал да горя не знал, но вот беда, одного солнечного утра нам сказали что контора закрывается. Пришлось искать другую работу. Нашел, программист php, но языка то я не знаю!

Ничего, взял тестовое задание, взял справочник, почитал что куда, за неделю написал и устроился на работу.

К чему всё это я ? К тому что если будет необходимость и желание то всего можно достичь, **и не важно какой будет самоучитель/справочник!**

ЗЫ: перед этим я немного баловался с дельфи

Answer (score 1):

http://PHP.SU + Расковырять несколько CMS систем. Я сам самоучка, и когда начинал лет так пять назад, именно так понял что такое PHP и как с ним бороться.

**UPD** // CMS систему предложил бы для ковыряния Open SLAED http://www.slaed.net/files-view-1103.html

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробивать!

Comment: кого? :DDDD

Comment: Open SLAED

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую начать с уроков интернет-университета [**intuit.ru**](http://intuit.ru) , так как сам с них начинал и получил более чем исчерпывающие знания PHP. Далее, чтоб попробовать на практике что-то поинтереснее рекомендую книжечку [**"PHP5 на примерах"**](http://progbook.ru/2008/08/01/php-5-na-primerakh-maksim-kuznecov-igor.html) авторы: Максим Кузнецов, Игорь Симдянов, Сергей Голышев. Удачи в обучении ;)

Answer (score 0):

Совет в три шага.

шаг 1-й. Ничерта ты не поймешь из мануала по php, будь он трижды упрощен, пока не увидишь в живую как люди пишут рабочий код. По этому: находишь видеоуроки желательно Евгения Попова и смотришь теорию!

шаг 2-й. Если ты тщательно погрузился в дебри php программирования, после просмотра видеокурсов тебе не помещает профессиональная реабилитация. По этому: бери в руки книгу "Изучаем PHP и MySql" авторы: Мишель Е. Дэвис и Джон А.Филипс и читай от корки до корки. Лучше этой книги сложно найти!

шаг 3-й. Ставишь пред собой конкретную задачу, желательно зафиксировать на бумаге и решаешь ее. Помощь найдешь на форумах [ирбис](http://www.irbis-team.com) и [Хэшкод](http://hashcode.ru)

Comment: > находишь видеоуроки желательно Евгения Попова

Тут каждый пятый дебильный вопрос на тему "как исправить нерабочий код, писал по видеоуроку". Дальше не читал, для минуса достаточно.

Comment: А что тебя пугает в видеоуроках? Сам то ты много книг прочитал? Буду спорить, из всего множества советчиков отвечающих на "дебильные вопросы" считают себя мощными программистами, хотя на самом деле таковыми не являются.

Comment: @NeonDT, по его ответам и комментариям, я думаю, он может себе позволить критику. А Попов реально хрень.  
P.S.: не перевариваю видеоуроки по своей сути. Только мануалы, книги, форумы.

Comment: Construct, я люблю критику, но конструктивно изложенную. Попов действительно не ахти! Но из рунетовского мусора сложно найти что-то более менее осмысленное.Предложи альтернативный видеоурок, не спорю, что он может быть лучше. Еще раз обращаю особое внимание: современная молодежь ужасно ленивая и заставить новичка читать мануалы практически не реально. А в вопросе "ka5itoshka" как раз и просит хороший самоучитель для новичков. Так что "ka5itoshka" предложений тебе по обучению хоть отбавляй, выбирай и учись, видишь какую дискуссию развели ради твоего светлого будущего, так что не подведи, учись

Comment: Попов вообще молодец, предпренимательный тип, но лезет он в сферу в которой сам не до конца разобрался (если хоть вообще разобрался), по этому много критики со стороны других. Язык програмирования это не панацея, любой язык осваивается за короткое время, главное знать не синтаксис, а основы, алгоритмы, умение мыслить и составлять алгоритмы самому. Тогда и прийдет к вам муза.

Comment: @NeonDT, я так считаю, что тот, кто считает (или хочет в будущем считать) себя настоящим программистом, должен уж по меньшей мере уметь принимать обучающие материалы не в самом безумно-разжёванном виде.  
Мануалы, конечно, для самого начала, лучше не использовать, то есть надо сначала общие моменты понять, типа вступления в ЯП. В том же PHP, к примеру, я бы советовал в качестве вступления обязательно новые материалы по безопасности и примерам как писать нельзя.  
А вот когда уже разобрался в общем, то дальше можно и на манула подсесть (самое лучшее - оригинальная документация на английском)..

Comment: @NeonDT видео не дает: базу алгоритмов; знание тонкостей, парадигм, паттернов; теорию (нет, не "геттеры в php", а "принципы работы процессора"/"особенности протокола UDP"/"проектирование приложений" etc); практических навыков. 

Из этого довольно просто сделать вывод, что видео может быть пригодно для повышения квалификации профессионалов (в формате вебинаров/мастер-классов), но бесполезно и даже вредно для новичков. Потому что ленивое школоло надо [отучать от наркотиков](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9NMS1-JTPg), а не подносить все на блюдечке.

Comment: Construct, неужели ты предлагаешь НОВИЧКУ читать оригинальную документацию на АНГЛИЙСКОМ?!

Comment: Sh4dow, ну всё намешал и парадигмы и паттерны и наркотики. :-)